# DataFrame to List format

Tags: python, pandas

Im converting DataFrame into List using following code

```
resultDataFrame = []
resultDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(resultDataFrame, columns=('day', 'hour', 'minute'))
```

and appending values ...

```
resultDataFrame.to_dict('l')
{'day': [6], 'hour': [12], 'minute': [54]}
```

But, I want to get it like

```
{'day': 6, 'hour': 12, 'minute': 54}
```

How to change the format?

Comment: How does it working?

Answer (score 2):

You can select first row for `Series` e.g. by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and create `dict` by [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'day': [6], 'hour': [12], 'minute': [54]})
print (df)
   day  hour  minute
0    6    12      54

print (df.iloc[0])
day        6
hour      12
minute    54
Name: 0, dtype: int64

print (df.iloc[0].to_dict())
{'day': 6, 'minute': 54, 'hour': 12}
```

Another possible solution is convert to `records` - `list of dict` and select by indexing:

```
print (df.to_dict('r'))
[{'day': 6, 'minute': 54, 'hour': 12}]

print (df.to_dict('r')[0])
{'day': 6, 'minute': 54, 'hour': 12}
```